# testng - skip multiple tests

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a test a case that if fails, 100 more tests would fail. These 100 tests are in different test classes. It is cumbersome to use `dependsOnMethod` on all of these tests. Is there a more maintainable appreach to skip these 100 tests should the first test fail?

## info:

- All of the tests are in the same Test Suite.
- Test classes are in different `<test>`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do this:

1. Create an implementation of `IInvokedMethodListener` and within its `beforeInvocation` check if an attribute (which is used to detect failures) has been set to indicate failures. If this attribute is set, then you mark your test method as skipped, set an exception to it and throw an exception from within `beforeInvocation`
2. Within the `afterInvocation()` implementation, check if the test method that was executed failed. If yes, then set the failure attribute at the suite object level.

Just ensure that you don't run tests in parallel with this setup, because this logic will not work when tests run concurrently.

Below sample shows all of this in action.

Here's the failure detecting listener.

```java
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class EarlyFailureDetectingListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
  private static final String SKIP_FURTHER_EXECUTION = "skipFurtherExecution";

  @Override
  public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (testResult
        .getTestContext()
        .getSuite()
        .getAttributeNames()
        .contains(SKIP_FURTHER_EXECUTION)) {
      testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
      IllegalStateException exception = new IllegalStateException("Failure detected");
      testResult.setThrowable(exception);
      String msg =
          String.format(
              "Skipping execution of %s.%s()",
              method.getTestMethod().getTestClass().getRealClass().getName(),
              method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
      System.err.println(msg);
      throw exception;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
      testResult.getTestContext().getSuite().setAttribute(SKIP_FURTHER_EXECUTION, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how the test classes look like:

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassOne {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    Assert.fail("Simulating a failure");
  }

  @Test
  public void anotherTestMethod() {
    TestClassTwo.printer();
  }
}
```

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassTwo {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    printer();
  }

  @Test
  public void anotherTestMethod() {
    printer();
  }

  static void printer() {
    ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    String msg =
        String.format(
            "Executing ====> %s.%s() on Thread [%d]",
            result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getName(),
            result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.err.println(msg);
  }
}
```

```java
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassThree {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    printer();
  }

  @Test
  public void anotherTestMethod() {
    printer();
  }

  static void printer() {
    ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    String msg =
        String.format(
            "Executing ====> %s.%s() on Thread [%d]",
            result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getName(),
            result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.err.println(msg);
  }
}
```

Here's the suite xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="55160447_suite" parallel="false" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener
      class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.EarlyFailureDetectingListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="55160447_test_one">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassOne">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="55160447_test_two">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassTwo">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="55160447_test_three">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassThree">
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's the execution output:

```
...
... TestNG 7.0.0-beta3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
Executing ====> com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassOne.anotherTestMethod() on Thread [1]

java.lang.AssertionError: Simulating a failure

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassOne.testMethod(TestClassOne.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:570)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

PASSED: anotherTestMethod
FAILED: testMethod
java.lang.AssertionError: Simulating a failure
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassOne.testMethod(TestClassOne.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:570)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


Skipping execution of com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassTwo.anotherTestMethod()


===============================================Skipping execution of com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassTwo.testMethod()
    55160447_test_one
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Test ignored.

Test ignored.
SKIPPED: anotherTestMethod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure detected
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.EarlyFailureDetectingListener.beforeInvocation(EarlyFailureDetectingListener.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:88)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.BaseInvoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(BaseInvoker.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:547)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

SKIPPED: testMethod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure detected
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.EarlyFailureDetectingListener.beforeInvocation(EarlyFailureDetectingListener.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:88)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.BaseInvoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(BaseInvoker.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:547)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
    55160447_test_two
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================

Test ignored.

Skipping execution of com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassThree.anotherTestMethod()
Skipping execution of com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.TestClassThree.testMethod()

Test ignored.
SKIPPED: anotherTestMethod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure detected
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.EarlyFailureDetectingListener.beforeInvocation(EarlyFailureDetectingListener.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:88)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.BaseInvoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(BaseInvoker.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:547)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

SKIPPED: testMethod
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure detected
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55160447.EarlyFailureDetectingListener.beforeInvocation(EarlyFailureDetectingListener.java:18)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeBeforeInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:88)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.BaseInvoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(BaseInvoker.java:55)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:547)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
    55160447_test_three
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================

Test ignored.

===============================================
55160447_suite
Total tests run: 6, Passes: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 4
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not solve my issue because I do not want to skip all of the tests(I have some more tests after the first 100s. And they are not dependent on the first one. Hence, I do not want to skip them). The other problem with this is that it takes almost as much time.

Comment: @mahan - I believe that you should be able to solve your issue with the solution I shared as a reference one. What I have shared here is a concept of how you can establish interdependency between `<test>` tags. You should be able to build upon this. Based on how you have your dependency visualised, you can proceed further. With respect to time, yes it would, because we are running sequentially. There is no way of circumventing that. On another note, perhaps its time you relooked at how you are organizing your tests. I feel that the fundamental problem lies there.

Answer (score -1):

While I would still suggest to use either `dependsOnMethods` or structure your tests differently to solve your problem, you could also skip these tests programatically.

For this purpose, set up a [MethodInterceptor](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IMethodInterceptor.html). In the [TestContext](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestContext.html) you can call `setAttribute` to store a value indicating that your test failed, and then in the interceptor you can skip any method, by changing the list that it returns accordingly.

But like I said in the beginning, consider the additional complexity that this adds, compared to the rather simple `dependsOnMethods` approach.  Remind yourself that tests also serve the purpose to document things as well.